# How to maintain a file association when calling a program from a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-association

Is there a way to maintain the original file association when running a program from a batch file?

I created a batch file that calls a Windows program and performs some file maintenance. I changed the file association to the batch file. When I click on a file that's associated with that program, the batch file executes and opens the program but the file I click on isn't loaded. The original file association is lost.

This sorta makes sense because the CALL command within the batch file is once removed from the initial mouse-click that initiated the batch file.

Is there a syntax I can add that would pass the target file name to the batch file as a variable and append it to the CALL command line?

BTW, this is for an XP machine. Any assistance would be appreciated!

EDIT: here's the code I'm trying to write:

```
call "C:\Program Files\CorelDRAW X4\Programs\CorelDRW.exe"
:loop
if exist "C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\My Documents\corel user files\*.cdr" copy "C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\My Documents\corel user files\*.cdr" "C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\My Documents\corel user files\*.sav"
ping localhost -n 300 > nul
goto loop
```

I'm trying to protect CorelDraw's auto-save file. There's a bug whereby CorelDraw sometimes deletes the auto-save file during abnormal shut-down. I changed the .cdr file association so that clicking on a cdr file calls the batch file, which in turn calls Coreldraw and copies the auto-save file to a different filename. That part works, but I have to manually open the file I clicked on.

Ideally, I'd like to figure out a way to terminate the loop when I close CorelDraw, but I'll cross that bridge once I solve the file association problem.

EDIT2: Here is the result of echo `%CMDCMDLINE%`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\My Documents\corel user files\protect_autosave.bat"  "C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\My Documents\filename.cdr""
```

Comment: You may find that the `%CMDCMDLINE%` variable gives you what you need.

Comment: @Compo thanks for the tip, but %CMDCMDLINE% returns the entire command string so I'm not sure how to use that. 

BTW, this is my first comment in this forum. How do I add a linebreak in my comments? According to the linked page on mini-Markdown formatting, two spaces adds a linebreak but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Use `%*` to append all script arguments to the call. i.e. `call "C:\Program Files\CorelDRAW X4\Programs\CorelDRW.exe" %*`

Comment: @ginahoy, why not include in your question area, the string assigned to `%CMDCMDLINE%` so that we can see it. Also are you aware that arguments given to the batch script can be read already using special metavariables `%1`, `%2` etc. Also why change a file association? The easiest way to do this is to create a right click context menu entry so that whenever you select a `.cdr` file you get a menu allowing you to run the batch file.

Comment: @Compo, if there's a way to do this without changing file association, I'm all ears. It's been probably 10 years since I modified the Windows Explorer context menu but I'm sure I can figure that out. But I still need to figure out how to pass the target filename to the batch file. I added the result of `%CMDCMDLINE%` to my question. As you can see, it includes the entire command, not just the target filename.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, if you take a look at the value of the `%CMDCMDLINE%` variable, you can see that the `protect_autosave.bat` file was called with a single parameter. In your actual batch file that parameter can be directly referenced with a special metavariable, `%1`. So you have two options, parse `%CMDCMDLINE%` to retrieve the called files name, of use the special metavariable, _(easier)_. To create a context menu entry, you'd add a couple of registry keys relevant to the `HKCU\Software\Classes` file association, `.cdr`.

Comment: @Compo... excellent! I got it working now. Now for the final step... is there a way to detect when the application is closed that I could use to exit the loop and end the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood the requirements for the task the code to use in batch file `%ProgramFiles%\CorelDRAW X4\Programs\CorelFile.bat` is:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
"%ProgramFiles%\CorelDRAW X4\Programs\CorelDRW.exe" %*
for %%I in (%*) do if exist %%I copy /Y "%%~I" "%%~dpnI.sav" >nul
```

This batch file must be associated with file extension `.cdr` for example by importing following registry file on Windows XP and later Windows versions with administrator privileges:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.cdr]
@="CorelDrawFile"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CorelDrawFile]
@="Corel Draw Image"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CorelDrawFile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):22,25,50,72,6f,67,72,61,6d,46,69,6c,65,73,25,5c,43,6f,72,65,6c,44,52,\
  41,57,20,58,34,5c,50,72,6f,67,72,61,6d,73,5c,43,6f,72,65,6c,44,52,57,2e,65,\
  78,65,22,2c,30,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CorelDrawFile\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):22,25,50,72,6f,67,72,61,6d,46,69,6c,65,73,25,5c,43,6f,72,65,6c,44,52,\
  41,57,20,58,34,5c,50,72,6f,67,72,61,6d,73,5c,43,6f,72,65,6c,46,69,6c,65,2e,\
  62,61,74,22,20,22,25,31,22,00
```

It is also possible to register file extension `.cdr` with absolute paths with `REG_SZ` instead of using `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and `%ProgramFiles%` in paths.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.cdr]
@="CorelDrawFile"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CorelDrawFile]
@="Corel Draw Image"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CorelDrawFile\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\CorelDRAW X4\\Programs\\CorelDRW.exe\",0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CorelDrawFile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\CorelDRAW X4\\Programs\\CorelFile.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Windows Explorer calls for each selected *.cdr file the batch file on using context menu **Open** respectively on double clicking a single *.cdr file.

The batch file starts *Corel Draw* with all the arguments passed to the batch file passing to *Corel Draw*. This is usually just the file name of the *.cdr file with full path and file extension enclosed in double quotes.

After *Corel Draw* terminated, the batch file checks for existence of each file specified as command line argument and copies the file with same name in same directory with different file extension `.sav`.

The batch file is designed for being started with multiple *.cdr file names specified as arguments on command line. I don't know if *Corel Draw* supports multiple *.cdr files being specified on command line.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%*` (batch file) and `%1` (Windows registry).
- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`

Comment: Thanks, @Mofi. That's a lot to absorb. It may be a few days before I find time to review (just broke ground on a new house, sorta up to my rear end in alligators at the moment! =:-o